# In Yahoo Mail, how can I change the "base name" of a disposable email address

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo

In Yahoo Mail, it's possible to create "disposable" email addresses consisting of two parts, an arbitrary "base name" and a "keyword".

Once set, is it possible to delete and start over with a different base name?

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to change it too. It seems that you can't. The UI confused me and I ended up having a really stupid basename. See this [link](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28338.html) for more info.

> Important - Once you create a base name, it's locked into your account
>   and cannot be edited or removed. If you'd like a different base name,
>   you can create a new Yahoo Mail account and add 1 base name to it.

You may try contacting their "tech support" but being a free account, I think they'll just ignore us.